# "no matching cipher found" error in `rsync`

Tags: ssh, rsync, encryption

I am trying to copy a directory from one system to another with `rsync`; but it erred. Can you please advise me on what to check?

#### Command:

```
[M root@aMachine ~]# rsync -e "ssh -c blowfish" -v -a /home/aDir/ root@192.168.0.1:/home/aDir
```

#### Output:

```
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: no matching cipher found
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]
```

I tried couple attempts in `/etc/ssh_config`, but to no avail. This is what I have in my `/etc/ssh_config` now:

```
# Host *
# ...
# ...
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2,1
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
IdentityFile /root/.ssh/identity
IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa
IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_dsa
IdentityFile /etc/static_keys/CURRENT
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to force the use of the `blowfish` cipher ("`ssh -c blowfish`"). According to your configuration, this cipher is not available (the SSH configuration, by default, shows the default configuration settings as comments).

Unless you have any compelling reason to do so (none was mentioned in your post), do not force the use of a particular cipher.

Notice also that you usually do not have to fiddle with `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`. As a user, it's easier to modify `$HOME/.ssh/config`. You *are* working on this system as a non-root user, aren't you?

Comment: Yes, blowfish is not available. Thanks for the suggestion of not using cipher. I just skipped the cipher altogether for now.